# Please clarify. Who precisely is able to vote on protocol changes?

Tags: baking, voting, governance

Who can precisely vote on protocol changes/proposals? Is it just bakers?

I understand that delegators give up their voting right to the bakers to whom they delegate, right?

And what about people who possess effectively more than the threshold of 10,000 tez, but are NOT acting as a baker, at the moment of the vote?

I mean: i guess i want to know the **exact requirement or proof**. what is the specific "proof" which must be provided by a voter to be allowed to vote? for what parameters is the blockchain exctly "scanning" to check whether one should be allowed to vote or not?

Answer (score 4):

Only bakers can vote, in order to be a baker you need 1 roll delegated to you (currently 10,000 xtz). Otherwise you can delegate your xtz to any baker that you trust with your vote. If baker A will vote Yay and you disagree then move your delegation to baker B which will vote Nay.

Comment: As a follow up point to this, there is plenty of time built in to the voting process to change your delegate in time to make your XTZ go to a baker/delegate whose vote is aligned with what you'd like to see.

Comment: Arthur + @lostdorje  thanks! one follow-up: "...to a baker whose vote is aligned..." ... and how can you exactly find out whether a Baker intends to vote yes/nay?  

And you must essentially find that out BEFORE the vote process starts, right?  Because when the vote process starts, the baker can already use your voting rights, and it would be too late for you to change the baker.  right? How to prevent such situation?  

Would be great to have some sort of platform where you see in advance each bakers voting intention on each upcoming proposal...?